# Iterating through a JSON object to get specific values

Tags: python, json, loops, flask

I wrote web app in flask to receive POST  request from another app in JSON format...

```
import os
from flask import Flask,request,json,abort

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook',methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.json)
        return '',200
    else:
        abort(400)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

the data I get :

```
{'channel': {'address': '00000', 'name': "nobody's Talking": 0000", 'uuid': 'fec375b2-d025-4a89-8688-2b1785dfb5d4'}, 'contact': {'name': 'Nets', 'urn': 'tel:+256704909243', 'uuid': 'af7065f4-192f-4a3a-9e08-75828394fb99'}, 'flow': {'name': 'webhook-test', 'revision': 4, 'uuid': '5041343f-4364-4518-a000-f4a4a7ff657f'}, 'input': {'attachments': [], 'channel': {'address': '00000', 'name': "nobody's Talking: 00000", 'uuid': 'fec375b2-d025-4a89-8688-2b1785dfb5d4'}, 'created_on': '2020-01-28T10:48:57.778339+03:00', 'text': 'whtest', 'type': 'msg', 'urn': {'display': '0704 909243', 'path': '+254704888680', 'scheme': 'tel'}, 'uuid': '554e6bfb-695e-4692-94ff-7ea9bfd936d0'}, 'path': [{'arrived_on': '2020-01-28T10:48:57.778606+03:00', 'exit_uuid': '', 'node_uuid': '23c305fb-da32-4217-9cf0-9bbf5d70ae56', 'uuid': '3a18d969-4880-484a-826a-60f18483623e'}], 'results': {}, 'run': {'created_on': '2020-01-28T10:48:57.778600+03:00', 'uuid': '32ec37f1-1ef6-4460-af89-305903114096'}}
```

I want to iterate through this json object and retrieve only three items from the object. I have not worked with json before. Here is my attempt

```
def rp_webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        results=(request.json)
        for i in jsonobj['results']:
            print(i['date created'],['flow'],['display'])
        return '',200
    else:
        abort(400)
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? It's confusing because, for instance, `urn` is defined twice in your JSON, both as a string element, and as an object.

Comment: Hint: there's no such thing as a "json object". JSON is a text format, once unserialized what you have is a plain Python object - usually (as in your case) a `dict` containing nested `dict`s and `list`s.

Comment: @Rúben   sorry about that I have edited it... 
 'date created',flow: name and the display

Comment: What you show above as "data I get" is neither JSON nor is it Python code declaring a `dict`. Hint: Use `repr()` to print stuff for debugging, not `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve the specific items from the JSON... with this code

```
def rp_webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        results= request.json
        x=json.dumps(results)
        y=json.loads(x)
```